# How do I use different currencies VBA

Tags: excel, vba, currency, vba7

I'm making a price scraper using VBA, so I can put the values nicely organized in Excel. But this scraper takes different currencies. When it puts a value with $ in front of it, it defaults to a currency cell, which is good. But when I put for example a value with € in front of it, it defaults to a general cell. How can I fix it and make it work with all currencies? I feed the values to the cells as strings.

Comment: Separate the currency symbol into one cell and the numeric value into another. Then set the formatting as needed.

Comment: The manual helps here: [Format numbers as currency](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-currency-0a03bb38-1a07-458d-9e30-2b54366bc7a4)